# jQuery before adding elements act strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please go to the jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tpm3ods/1/).
Click the last image with the "+" sign, this will open a popup with an ADD button, please click it.

The problem is, and I can't figure it out, why if I add multiple elements (clicking the `ADD` multiple times, like 4-5 times) the distance between the new elements is smaller than the distance between the predefined elements? I am using the same CSS for it, the same HTML structure.

Comment: You have to provide MCVE in question itself

Comment: It is a closed project, I can only show the website URL for now.

Comment: You are right, I'm making a jsfiddle now.

Comment: I guess making jsFiddle, you should be able to detect issue, making it minimalistic until issue disappears

Comment: I made a jsFiddle, please see now :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

Comment: @HerrSerker Just need to include jQuery UI but unrelevant to issue

Comment: I've updated my question + the jsFiddle. Now it doesn't have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that `<li>` tags have a natural spacing.

You have a few options:

- Either stop using li tags and use something else.
- `<li>` tag for each row, like it should be.
- Change natural `<li>` behaviour

`li {
  display: table;
}`

**Edit:**
Another option, as mentioned by Florin, is:

```
a {
  float: left
}
```

Anyway, it's all about the `li` behaviour. There are many ways to solve it.

Comment: Yes, but if you check my original post, in the url: www.florin-pop.com/work/Bookmarks, the other li is having multiple rows too.. And the glitch is only when adding new elements.

Comment: I also need to add display:table-cell to the a, and float: left... This way I can achieve what I want. Please add this to your question and I'll mark it as correct!

Comment: Also, a faster solution was to add float:left to the a tags. This removed the unwanted whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You use inline-block for the images.
The images are layout by using `display: inline-block`.
In your HTML code you have whitespace between the images. That whitespace is shown in the website.
The programmatically added images are inserted without whitespace between them, so they are nearer together.

Check here for strategies against the whitespace: 
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I add to the a tags:

```
a { 
    float:left;
}
```

it will remove the unwanted whitespace.